# Play java application accessing a Web Service through an Authenticating Proxy

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.3

I am developing a Play Java application and it needs to connect to another REST service using the Play WS API (JavaWS) through an Authenticating Proxy (i.e. the proxy requires username/password).

First I tried using the JVM options given below when starting the Play app.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy_server_hostname> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy_server_port> -Dhttp.proxyUser=<username> -Dhttp.proxyPassword=<password>
```

Above didn't work fully. Application was able to connect to the proxy server without any issue, but proxy server is returning PROXY_AUTH_REQUIRED error which suggests that -Dhttp.proxyUser and -Dhttp.proxyPassword JVM options didn't work.

I searched and found the following two links which shows how to do this in a typical Java application.

http://memorynotfound.com/configure-http-proxy-settings-java/
http://rolandtapken.de/blog/2012-04/java-process-httpproxyuser-and-httpproxypassword

As suggested in these two links, I modified my Play application's onStart method in Global.java as below,

```
@Override
public void onStart(Application application) {
    //Proxy authentication begin
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<proxy_server_hostname>");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<proxy_server_port>");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "<username>");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "<password>");

    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            if (getRequestorType() == RequestorType.PROXY) {
                String prot = getRequestingProtocol().toLowerCase();
                String host = System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyHost", "");
                String port = System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyPort", "");
                String user = System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyUser", "");
                String password = System.getProperty(prot + ".proxyPassword", "");

                if (getRequestingHost().equalsIgnoreCase(host)) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(port) == getRequestingPort()) {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
    //Proxy authentication end
}
```

With the above modification I started the Play application *without specifying the previously mentioned JVM options (as I an now giving the same in the code). But the result remained the same. The proxy server still returns PROXY_AUTH_REQUIRED error message to the application. Again the application is connecting to the proxy server with the above code modification, but Java Authenticator seems not submitting the proxy username and password to the proxy server.

Or is there a different approach to do this in a Play Java application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Network Authentication : Class Authenticator

```
-   The class Authenticator represents an object that knows how to obtain authentication for a network connection. Usually, it will do this by prompting
    the user for information.
- Can be used when credential need to be sent over network.
```

[Authenticator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html)

Comment: In the link you shared, you have not read the complete description it seems.. :| In my second technique (i.e. connecting with proxy programmatically), I have done exactly what is mentioned in the remainder of the Javadoc link you shared. It is how we should programmatically connect to an authenticating proxy, but it is not working in Play Java.

Comment: Thanks, I read it and used it will SOAP WS and it is working perfect for me even in proxy. In my case, found some issue while setting system properties however resolved successfully.

Comment: Did you try from a Play Java app?

Comment: Unfortunately then this answer is of no use to my question. Thus, I am down voting.

Comment: It's you call and have checked property name once bcz the same I face once working with SOAP lib.